# AspectJ wrap @Around annotation around dependency classes

Tags: java, gradle, aop, aspectj

I have an AspectJ AOP class in package `a` that wraps around any class with a particular annotation.

I want to move my AOP class to package `b`, which consumes package `a`, and still get it to execute the code I want for classes in package `a` with the specified annotation. I've tried moving my AOP class, but I'm not seeing its code get executed.

Do I need to configure my AOP class a certain way to achieve this or is that just not possible. 
Btw, I'm configuring with Gradle.

Comment: Please show us your AOP annotation setting. I guess your AOP annotation setting should be changed according to moving the package.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I support what @hiropon said. Please be advised to learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is in order to know how to ask good questions with a good prospect of receiving a helpful answer. SO is about code, not about ambiguous and abstract prose. I can think of at least 10 different reasons why your AOP application does not run as expected, but I want to analyse, not to guess, because this is not a quiz show. ;-) Thank you very much.